# Difficulty using sp_OAMethod [MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP] to post multipart/form-data

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, multipartform-data

Code attempts to post a multpart form to API service. which does not recognize it as multipart.
(Content should be multipart)

The request works fine in Postman, I think I could trouble shoot it if I could see the actual HTTP request being sent.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[test_QAAPI_attachments]
    as 
    BEGIN
    
    SET TEXTSIZE -1;
    
    Declare @Object as Int;
    DECLARE @hr  int;
    Declare @json as table(Json_Table nvarchar(max));
    DECLARE @contentType VARCHAR(8000);
    DECLARE @contentTypeForm VARCHAR(8000);
    Declare @url as Varchar(2048);
    Declare @errorDesc as nvarchar (max);
    Declare @len as int;
    
    DECLARE @resp int;
    DECLARE @jsonText nvarchar(max);
    DECLARE @authHeader as varchar(4000);
    DECLARE @ret Int;
    DECLARE @token Int;
    DECLARE @responseText VARCHAR(8000);
    
    DECLARE @runMode as varchar(5);  -- run, test, train 
    
    SET @contentType = 'application/json';
    SET @contentTypeForm = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
    
    DECLARE @moduleReference varchar(2);
    DECLARE @formattedAccount varchar(21);
    DECLARE @fileBinary as varbinary(max)
    Declare @jsonReturned as varchar(max)
    
    Set @errorDesc = 'No Errors'
    
    SET @contentType = 'application/json';
    set @url =  'https://qaapi71.auth.civicalg.com/main/api/v2/authority/login'
    
    SET @jsonText =
    '{
      "userName": "apitest",
      "password": "[REMOVED]"
    }'
    
    -- Getting the accessToken from Authority API...
    Exec @hr=sp_OACreate 'MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP', @Object OUT
    EXEC @hr= sp_OAMethod @Object, 'open', NULL, 'post', @url, 'false'
    EXEC sp_OAMethod @Object, 'SETRequestHeader', null, 'Content-Type', 'application/json'
    EXEC sp_OAMethod @Object, 'send', null, @jsonText
    EXEC sp_OAMethod @Object, 'responseText', @json OUT
    
    INSERT into @json (Json_Table) exec sp_OAGetProperty @Object, 'responseText'
    
    Select @authHeader =  'Bearer ' + f.accessToken 
        
    FROM OPENJSON(
    (select * from @json), N'$.result')
    WITH (   
        accessToken nvarchar(4000) N'$.accessToken'
        
    ) as f
    
    Delete @json
    
    DECLARE @formBody varchar(max);
    
    set @url= 'https://qaapi71.auth.civicalg.com/main/api/v2/recordManagement/attachments'
    
    -- text below copied directly from successful Postman http request...
    SET @formBody='
    ----------------------------028844704192657132624492
    Content-Disposition: form-data; name="apiVersion"
    2
    ----------------------------028844704192657132624492
    Content-Disposition: form-data; name="ModuleReference"
    DD
    ----------------------------028844704192657132624492
    Content-Disposition: form-data; name="FormattedAccount"
    002.2020.00005653.001
    ----------------------------028844704192657132624492
    Content-Disposition: form-data; name="ExternalDocumentType"
    UPLOAD
    ----------------------------028844704192657132624492
    Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Description"
    some description
    ----------------------------028844704192657132624492
    Content-Disposition: form-data; name="FileName"
    test.jpg
    ----------------------------028844704192657132624492
    Content-Disposition: form-data; name="FileUpload"; filename=""
    ----------------------------028844704192657132624492--'
    
    -- final [--] indicates the end.
    
    DECLARE @boundary as varchar(200)
    SET @boundary='----------------------------028844704192657132624492'
    DECLARE @L as varchar(20)
    
    SET @L=CAST (len(@formBody) as varchar)
    
    
    -- Open the connection.
    EXEC @ret = sp_OACreate 'MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP', @token OUT;
    IF @ret <> 0 RAISERROR('Unable to open HTTP connection.', 20, 3);
    
    -- Send the request.
    EXEC @ret = sp_OAMethod @token, 'Open', null, 'POST', @Url, 'false';
    EXEC @ret = sp_OAMethod @token, 'setRequestHeader', NULL, 'Authorization', @authHeader;
    EXEC @ret = sp_OAMethod @token, 'setRequestHeader', NULL, 'Content-Length',@L;
    EXEC @ret = sp_OAMethod @token, 'setRequestHeader', NULL, 'Content-Type','multipart/form-data','boundary',@boundary;
    EXEC @ret = sp_OAMethod @token, 'send',NULL, @formBody;
    
    EXEC sp_OAMethod @token, 'responseText', @responseText OUTPUT
    
    INSERT into @json (Json_Table) exec sp_OAGetProperty @token, 'responseText'
    
    select @formBody
    
    select * from @json
    
    END
```

Comment: Don't do it in SQL Server! It's totally the wrong place.

Comment: And no one is going to debug that massive SP for you.

Comment: It's a mystery to me that the `sp_OAXxx` methods haven't been deprecated. If you're going to invoke foreign code from SQL Server, it's far more sensible to use the SQL CLR integration and modern development tools. It's remarkably difficult to write `sp_OAXxx` based code that works correctly including in error paths.

Comment: This task should really be done outside of SQL Server. While the `sp_OA*` methods exist in SQL Server using them doesn't help with server stability and realiability. There's no error checking going on here, no trapping of exceptions, no destroying of OLE objects after use. This code will be leaking resources.

Comment: The best bit is you could do this in about four lines of Powershell. If you need to fire this from SQL Server then create an Agent Job to do it